# How to create pretty url in yii for module

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I have searched a lot and tried a lot to do this , but no luck . I have referred this [LINK](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/21884-module-and-url-management/). But it didn't solve my problem . I have a user module installed in yii (yii 2) . and i have user profile url like

http://192.168.1.31/Eb/user/profile?uguid=ac0c4558-77fc-4896-9b30-f77afe4d81cd

---

but i want this to like

http://192.168.1.31/Eb/user/profile/ac0c4558-77fc-4896-9b30-f77afe4d81cd

---

I mean without guid query string parameter . 
I am trying in url manager like this

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'showScriptName'=>false,
                'rules'=>array(
           '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<guid:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
```

How it is possible ??

Answer (score 0):

In Yii [UrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) keys of `rules` parameter (attribute) must be **regex pattern**.
If I understand true your url have a structure CONTROLLER/ACTION (in my case `Eb` is subfolder), so your rules must be:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
   'showScriptName'=>false,
   'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<uguid:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
)
```

Be careful, that your `uguid`  parameter not number so you must **use `w+` instead of `d+`**

So you can create urls using [createUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#creating-urls):

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('user/profile', array('uguid' => 'USER_ID'))
```

Result must give which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your current url can also be accessed using

```
http://192.168.1.31/Eb/user/profile/uguid/ac0c4558-77fc-4896-9b30-f77afe4d81cd
```

You can remove your controller name by adding the following line in urlmanager rules:

```
'/Eb/user/profile/<id:([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)' => 'Eb/user/profile/uguid/<id>'
```

That should do the trick :)